# Javascript text input change handler combined with div click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, events, jquery-events

I have the following situation. ([A jsfiddle of this can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/BcMZM/))

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="text" id="txtBox" />

    <div>
        <div class="option">Option 1</div>
        <div class="option">Option 2</div>
        <div class="option">Option 3</div>
    </div>

    <div id="out"></div>
</div>​
```

**Javascript (jQuery)**

```
$(".option").click(function(){
    $("#out").append("<br/>clicked " + $(this).html());
    $("#txtBox").val($(this).html());
});

$("#txtBox").change(function(){
    $("#out").append("<br/>changed value to " + $(this).val());
});
```

​
The idea is that a user can type a value in the textbox, or alternatively pick one from the list of options. The chosen value is written to a database using an ajax call, if the user types in a value it triggers the change handler on the textbox, if an option is clicked instead, the click handler is used.

**The problem is in the following steps:**

- type some random value in the textbox
- click an option
- *->The change handler AND the click handler are triggered together.*

Now this last situation is extremely undesirable because the change handler is triggered using the random value that was in the textbox, **AND** the click handler is triggered using the option's html attribute.

What I want is just the click handler executing and the change handler doing nothing in this situation (or another solution that produces the effect of just one single action being taken in each of the possible use cases. Does anyone have an idea how to approach this?

Comment: The change handler executes whenever you change focus away from #txtBox and the contents of #txtBox have changed. Whenever you click on one of the options, #txtBox loses focus and so if the conents of #txtBox have changed, the change handler will run. You need to decide when you want the change handler to run. Do you want it to run in the current conditions but not when an option is clicked?

Comment: This is just an example of a quite common situation, when you have a `blur`/`focusout` event listener but you want it to do stuff depending on the new active element. Unofrtunately, there's no `relatedTarget` property that can help up, like for `mouseout`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your click handler to the mousedown event:

```
$(".option").mousedown(function(){
    $("#out").append("<br/>clicked " + $(this).html());
    $("#txtBox").val($(this).html());
});
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/CAUQv/

You could also bind the the `keyup` event instead, that way, you're detecting every change performed by actual typing:

```
$("#txtBox").keyup(function(){
    $("#out").append("<br/>changed value to " + $(this).val());
});
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/RZmtz/

**Documentation**

- `jQuery.mousedown` - http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/
- `jQuery.keyup` - http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Comment: Ah, yes, `mousedown` is fired before `blur`/`change`. Good point.

Comment: Will this work if you use the mouse to paste or drag text into the input field?

Comment: The drag-and-drop scenario isn't handled by any of the suggested code here, or the OP code (at least in Firefox) -- the `change` event isn't fired at all if you try any of this code! Pasting is fine with `change`, but not with `keyup`

Comment: @Chris the change listener will only fire when you blur the input field. So +1 for `keyup`. I would suggest to use a combination of `keyup` and `change` though.

Answer (score 3):

You could build in a [timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) in the input's value change handler and [clear it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout) in the option click handler.

```
var myTimeout;

$(".option").click(function(){
  clearTimeout(myTimeout);
  $("#out").append("<br/>clicked " + $(this).html());
  $("#txtBox").val($(this).html());
});

$("#txtBox").change(function(){
  myTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    $("#out").append("<br/>changed value to " + $("#txtBox").val());
  }, 50);
});
```

Comment: Will this work if you use the mouse to paste or drag text into the input field? http://jsfiddle.net/fZnQy/ :p

Comment: It should, because the value changes. ;-)

Comment: There was a bug in my code. Since the change function was wrapped in a `setTimeout` I should have used `$("#txtBox").val()` instead of `$(this).val()` http://jsfiddle.net/fZnQy/1/

Comment: I thought of using a timeout myself but this seems quite ugly to me ;)

Answer (score 1):

An alternate option would be to "disable" the options if the user types something into the box:

http://jsfiddle.net/BcMZM/2/

```
$(".option").click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("disabled")) return false;

    $("#out").append("<br/>clicked " + $(this).html());
    $("#txtBox").val($(this).html());
});

$("#txtBox").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == '') return false;

    $("#out").append("<br/>changed value to " + $(this).val());
});

$("#txtBox").keyup(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();     

    if (val != '')
        $(".option").addClass("disabled");
    else
        $(".option").removeClass("disabled");
});
```

Comment: Will this work if you use the mouse to paste or drag text into the input field?

Comment: @JasperdeVries I don't believe so. The `keyup` event has to be fired.

Comment: This doesn't work for me as my goal is to filter the options using the value from the textbox. Could be a solution for other situations maybe.

Answer (score 0):

```
var delay = (function(){
 var timer = 0;
 return function(callback, ms){
  clearTimeout (timer);
  timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
 };
})(jQuery);

var clickedOption = false;
$(".option").click(function(){
 clickedOption = true;
 $("#out").append("<br/>clicked " + $(this).html());
 $("#txtBox").val($(this).html());
});

$("#txtBox").change(function(){
var changeThis = $(this);
delay(function(){
if(!clickedOption){ $("#out").append("<br/>changed value to " + changeThis.val()); }
clickedOption = false;
}, 50 );

});
```